# Concurrent users count from log file

Tags: r

I am looking for the quickest approach to analyze log files where there are two columns of interest: `login_time` and `logout_time` to get the concurrent user count logged into the system in a specific range of time (`bin`).

Approach #1 gives the correct count per bin but loops are discouraged in R so I suppose it will fail for bigger logs (I expect the files to contain even hundreds of thousands of rows). I used a list so that the object is modified in place (checked with `address()` from `pryr` library).

Approach #2 is what I thought might be quicker but it does not work the way I would like it to.
Now it recycles `bins` and gives the result for each `hist`'s row.
I would like to get a 2D matrix so that I could then sum rows to get the same result as from Approach #1.
I am afraid though that this approach may be not memory efficient.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

bins <- seq(ymd_hms("2020-09-01 00:00:00"), ymd_hms("2020-09-01 01:00:00"), by = dminutes(15))
n_bins <- length(bins)
hist <- tibble(login_time = rep(ymd_hms("2020-09-01 00:20:00"), 10),
               logout_time = rep(ymd_hms("2020-09-01 00:40:00"), 10))
concurrent_users_list <- list(bin = bins, count = 0)

# Approach #1

for (x in 1:nrow(hist)) {
  hist_row <- hist[x, ]
  bin_first <- floor((hist_row$login_time - ymd_hms("2020-09-01 00:00:00")) / dminutes(15))
  bin_last <- ceiling((hist_row$logout_time - ymd_hms("2020-09-01 00:00:00")) / dminutes(15))

  to_add <- list(x = c(rep(0, bin_first), rep(1, bin_last - bin_first), rep(0, n_bins - bin_last + 1)))
  
  concurrent_users_list[["count"]] <-
    concurrent_users_list[["count"]] + to_add$x
}
concurrent_users_list
#> $bin
#> [1] "2020-09-01 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-09-01 00:15:00 UTC"
#> [3] "2020-09-01 00:30:00 UTC" "2020-09-01 00:45:00 UTC"
#> [5] "2020-09-01 01:00:00 UTC"
#> 
#> $count
#> [1]  0 10 10  0  0  0

# Approach #2

hist$login_time <= (bins + minutes(15)) & hist$logout_time >= bins
#>  [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Approach #1 is fine, but you could use `lapply` instead of a `for`-loop for improved efficiency. Just rewrite the loop into a function, and use `lapply(your_list, your_function)`

Comment: I think `for` loop or apply have the same efficiency

Comment: I rewrote #1 as
`test_fun1 <- function(concurrent_users_list) {
  bin_first <- floor((sess_hist$login_time - ymd_hms("2020-09-01 00:00:00")) / dminutes(15))
  bin_last <- ceiling((sess_hist$logout_time - ymd_hms("2020-09-01 00:00:00")) / dminutes(15))
  to_add <- list(x = c(rep(0, bin_first - 1), rep(1, bin_last - bin_first + 1), rep(0, n_bins - bin_last)))
  
  concurrent_users_list[["count"]] <-
    concurrent_users_list[["count"]] + to_add$x
}

lapply(concurrent_users_list, test_fun1)`

but I get `Error in rep(0, bin_first - 1) : invalid 'times' argument`.